# What is a possible value for a Uint8Array typed variable in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, typeorm, uint8array

What are possible values if a variable inside an interface is typed as `Uint8Array`?

**typeorm/src/driver/sqljs/SqljsConnectionOptions.ts**
https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/src/driver/sqljs/SqljsConnectionOptions.ts

```
/**
 * Sql.js-specific connection options.
 */
export interface SqljsConnectionOptions extends BaseConnectionOptions {

    /**
     * A Uint8Array that gets imported when the connection is opened.
     */
    readonly database?: Uint8Array;
}
```

If already read [MDN's article on `Uint8Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Uint8Array), but it did not help.

**EDIT:** As you can see, there is a database name required. Intuitivly I would past in the name of my database, but this is a string. So how does a database in `Uint8Array` format look like?

Comment: What do you mean, it did not help? A variable declared as `Uint8Array` can have a value of `Uint8Array`, obviously. E.g. `new Uint8Array(10)` is a value it could have. What specifically is the problem you are having?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not a database *name*. It is a *database*. Reading up on what sql.js is will show you it is SQLite compiled into JavaScript through Emscripten, with an in-memory store. By default, it gives you a blank database, which will get forgotten when you stop using it; but you have an option of importing it from, or exporting it to, an `Uint8Array`, which is literally the byte-by-byte contents of your SQLite database file. Look at [sql.js readme](https://github.com/kripken/sql.js/) to see many examples of how to get the database array (from upload, from XHR, from Node.js reading of a file...).

Comment: This wasn't really clear for me. After reading more, I've understood the principles of `Unit8Array`, but please, this is not cristal clear and unintuitive.

Comment: What specifically wasn't clear? Do you have a SQLite database you wish to import? If you do, where is it? Are we talking clientside or serverside? The answer is as clear as the question lets it be; besides, the examples on the linked README address most scenarios.

Comment: I think you have missunderstood me, I am totally fine with your answer. I meant the reading for instance on MDN etc. You'r answer finally clearified everthing ;)

Comment: Ah I see. :) Cheers then!

Answer (score 1):

Type of data is gonna be an array of 8-bit unsigned integer.

If you're not familiar with it, this link explains well http://ctp.mkprog.com/en/ctp/unsigned_8bit_integer/

"8-bit unsigned integer type is used to store only pozitiv whole number. 8-bit unsigned integer and his value range: from 0 to 255."